# Software to make HDD to be a lazy copy of SSD?

Tags: windows-10, backup, hard-disk, ssd

I want to build a Windows 10 PC with 500GB SSD and 500GB HDD (and other disks, but they are not important in this question).

How to make that HDD to be a silent copy of the SSD? I mean all data on SSD should be "mirrored" on HDD in "lazy" mode.

I've read about RAIDs, but as I understood that is not exactly what I need, because in RAID SSD write speed will be limited by HDD's one.

So, maybe anybody know the way how to do that? What software I should use? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Are you asking us to recommend some software? That's what we do here, but I don't see it in your question, which is why it has been flagged as off-topic. If you edit it to ask for some software recommendation, then you will likely get an answer.

Comment: Your question is very interesting and relevant here if you are looking for a software recommendation.  As Mawg mentioned, please edit your question so it can be reopened.  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLizard is the edit good enough to un-hold?

Comment: You could install cygwin on your machine, and install `rsync` or `rdiff-backup` on it such that it unidirectionally copies all files (with some exceptions) from the SSD to the HDD whenever a change on the SSD occurs (even immediate file deletions can be made possible). I've never done such a setup though. I've also never usd the Windows port of these programs.

Comment: You tagged the question as backup. Are you aware that a copy as you describe will not be a backup? For the same reason RAID is not a backup. Maybe you could describe why you want such a non-RAID but similar to RAID solution.

Comment: I've reopened your question.  It's on the edge of what we allow, but I think it can generate good answers as it is written.

Comment: Have you tried SecondCopy?  Here's the url: http://www.secondcopy.com/  It might be exactly what you need.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard, yes, SecondCopy is exctly what I need. Thank You. Maybe You will post an answer?

Comment: I thought so!  I didn't have time to post a full answer, and I could tell you needed help right away.  I'll post a real answer for you (and everyone) later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Active disk cloning feature of [Acronis True Image 2019](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/true-image-features/) may do what you want. Another term they use is "Non-Stop Backup", which probably relates to an older version of their software.